# How can I scrape a website with several parameters in the URL for all ZIP records and store in CSV?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website (i.e. dealership list of a car brand) and would like to store all records into a CSV, of all fields, the ZIP has a variable range.

The URL is similar to:

https://www.brand-dealer-finder.com/find-dealership.html?brand=Ford&zipcode=12345&country=US

So, when I query the URL I get this result:

```
{ "DealerID": "Ford012", "City": "Oxford", "County": "Nevada", "phone": "12345678"}
```

This is fine for one single query. I would like to run a query for all ZIP codes starting with 00001 until 99999 and store the results in a column based file (i.e. CSV)

I managed to scrape and store 1 value. This is the code in Python:

```
import requests
import urllib, shutil

url = 'https://www.brand-dealer-finder.com/find-dealership.html?brand=Ford&zipcode=12345&country=US'

myfile = requests.get(url)
open('sample-data.txt', 'wb').write(myfile.content)
```

1) A way to query ZIP Codes 00001 to 99999, so adding a kind if "count +1"

2) A way to store the results column based instead of a string such as:

```
{ "DealerID": "Ford012", "City": "Oxford", "County": "Nevada", "phone": "12345678"}
```

Comment: This question is a bit broad as it sits. I'd recommend starting with one piece at a time, maybe how to store the file content as a csv. Objects from requests do have a `.json()` method, so maybe look at what `myfile.json()` does

Comment: Is that the actual URL? You mentioned that it is similar, but I cannot seem to access the site.

Comment: Hi @ajax1234, I guess I have found a solution otherwise I will comment again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might need 2 functions for this task:

1. Define a function that returns the url based on the zip, and,
2. Write to a file, using csv.

For the first task, we could do something like this:

```
# Importing
import requests
import urllib, shutil
import csv

# We define a class that receive the zip code and returns an object with the url and the zip code
class Zip:
  def __init__(self, zipCode):
    self.zipCode = zipCode
    self.url = 'https://www.brand-dealer-finder.com/find-dealership.html?brand=Ford&zipcode='+zipCode+'&country=US'

"""
    Here, we check the length of the number and the top, so we decide if we
    add zeros at the left
"""
def formatNumber(number, top):
  numberStr = str(number)
  zipCode = ''
  prefix = '0'
  topStr = str(top)
  # Defining the difference of length from both numbers
  lengthDiff = len(topStr) - len(numberStr)
  for n in range(0, lengthDiff):
    zipCode += prefix
  zipCode += numberStr
  return zipCode

def getUrlsBasedOnZip(start, end):
  listOfCodes = [] # Here we will store all the zip codes and urls
  for n in range (start, end):
    zipCode = formatNumber(n, end)
    zipObject = Zip(zipCode)
    listOfCodes.append(zipObject)
  return listOfCodes

def writeFile(file, content):
  try:
    with open(file, mode='a') as csv_file:
      writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file)
      writer.writerow(content)
  except:
    print ("Something bad happened while trying to write into the file!")

# After we have functions to write and get the urls based on zip, 
# we can scrape the page

def scrapePage(url, file_to_write):
  response = requests.get(url)
  writeFile(file_to_write, response.content)

def main():
  listOfZip = getUrlsBasedOnZip(1, 2000)
  for zip in listOfZip:
    scrapePage(zip.url, 'myfile.csv')
```

I have tested some code in local, but I can't test the scrape because I don't have the real URL.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your help! 
I tried to run it but get a Python error : Unexpected Unindent in this part. Do you happen to know why?

def scrapePage(url, file_to_write):
  try:
  response = requests.get(url)
  writeFile(file_to_write, response.content)

Comment: I think it is because I didn't put an except clause after "try", in writeFile. I edited my answer, please check if it is ok

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you (gracias!) that solved the issue.
Now I get an error for invalid syntax at the very end: listOfZip = getUrlsBasedOnZip

Do you happen to know why?

Comment: Yes! I'm sorry. There are a ":" after that line. I have edited. Please try and let me know if that resolve the issue